# How to save Django unsaved model with one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a Django 1.5 one to many relationship between 2 models. It looks something like this

```
class Team(models.Model):
    class Meta:
    league = models.ForeignKey(League,related_name="teams")
    ...

class League(models.Model):
    ...
```

Each League can have one or more teams. I am responding to a POST request on a League related URL and in the process of creating (or updating) a League. Teams can only be created indirectly through Leagues (ie. no POST of Team is supported) and each Team must have a League. However I cannot get it to work correctly.

In the `LeagueSerializer` I have overridden `from_native` and parsing json there (I do not have a `TeamSerializer`). When there is validation error from `full_clean()` I return None (from `from_native()`). In my view, after calling `LeagueSerializer.is_valid()` I check if `LeagueSerializer.object` is not `None`, and if it is not - I call `LeagueSerializer.save()`. And this seems to work great when I am not changing the teams in the League. Here is the snippet from `views.py` (as requested by TankorSmash)

```
def league_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #pass the incoming post data to league serializer
        serializer = LeagueSerializer(data=request.body)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            if serializer.object is None:
                print "something went awry in from_native. invalid/bad data in post"
            else:
                print "things seemed to have been ok in from_native"
                serializer.save()
```

Any attempt to add a team to unsaved league instance by calling league.teams.add(new_team) fails with Integrity error

```
IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

How can I save the unsaved `League` with one to many foreign key relationship ? I would like to keep the current processing flow.

EDIT -
I have since found a workaround to this.

1.I had to associate a League object from DB temporarily just so I can call new_team.full_clean(). Once that is done, I set new_team.league = new_league. This is so I can validate the new_team that will be eventually associated with the new_league that is not in DB yet.

2.In order to pass the new_team to my view, I introduced an unsaved_objects non-model list into League model. The view calls save() on the League object and then iterates unsaved_objects and calls save on each of those objects.

Here is what I have learnt so far about this - Django 1.5 does not provide a way for you to create a new League, a new team and associate the team with the league and call save once on any one object (be it serializer or a model) to save the League, its relationship to the team and the team. Django needs save on League followed by save on Team.

I call the above a workaround because it does not serve my purpose entirely. For example if team save fails, DB would have processed the League save already thus requiring me to track (a) when new_league is created so i can delete the new league (b) previous league contents when updating an existing league so i can revert to the previous league. If I could have a transaction across the save() calls, that would take care of this.

Querying db constantly for the temporary league is a waste.

Comment: It might help to show some more code, I'm having a hard time following your LeageSerializer explanation.

Comment: You have to save your `League` instance before you can add teams to it, because the `pk` is only generated by saving the `League` instance and the `pk` is necessary to associate teams with a particular `League`.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper - if I save the League instance and team fails validation, I would have to undo league save if the league was just created while attempting to process post. Besides I cannot see the flow of such an implementation clearly. Note that I have single save in the POST handler and I do not know of a way to pass multiple model instances from from_native back to my view.

Comment: You can use the information that the teams will be associated with a league in your validation steps. Validate the league, but don't save it yet. Pass the unsaved `league` object to your team validation code and use that instead of `self.league`. If that all works, save the league, then save each team (either setting its FK field directly or using `add`).

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper All my validation happens in the LeagueSerializer from_native. I am not sure what you are proposing here, could you post a snippet for your proposal ?

Answer (score 1):

> Any attempt to add a team to unsaved league instance by calling
>   league.teams.add(new_team) fails with Integrity error

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to save a `Team` to the DB but without fulfilling the foreign key to the league.  Try adding `blank=True, null=True` to the line of the `Team` model that defines `league`, allowing for a `Team` to be saved without an existing `League` to link to:

```
league = models.ForeignKey(League,related_name="teams", blank=True, null=True)
```

But I would first think that you're unable to save one model without a key to the second key. You can't save 'nothing' to the DB without explicitly saying so first.

Comment: An interesting idea, but there is a requirement that Team should not exist without a League and so blank=True, null=True sort of defeats that. I have updated my question with this requirement.

Comment: Aren't you then trying to do the impossible? You cannot save the key of the non-existant model (as far as the DB is concerned) to the DB. How is it supposed to save what doesn't yet exist?

Comment: I was hoping there is a way to add a team to an unsaved league and defer the integrity check to the point when league is saved. The issue is with saving, the add call is looking at what is in DB and it should not for my purposes. This is sometimes referred to as "forward reference"

Comment: A league must have a primary key before you can set anything to have a foreign key relationship to it. The `add` call on the inverse relationship created by the foreign key works by setting the foreign key field of the object you're attempting to `add`. It's not an integrity check, it's a logical requirement of the way the database works. Django does not provide an interface for placeholders that would be automatically filled in later.

Comment: Note that if i do new_team.league = league, that is OK ! The primary key on the unsaved League object is set. [the model uses its own primary key instead of django default pk]

Comment: @user3140390 - it looks to me like the fact that that doesn't raise an exception is a tracked bug in Django: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10811 Have you tested whether or not it actually saves the FK field as you're hoping?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper no i have not tested that. setting new_team.league to league is not very useful in terms of processing (it is somewhat useful in trying to understand Django behavior) because from_native cannot pass multiple object instances back to view. if i could pass new_team somehow along with my league instance then I am in business.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show the code where you're doing things like "using its own primary key" and using `from_native`.